# angular 2 custom sort pipe help me plase

Tags: typescript, ionic2, angular2-routing, angular2-template, angular2-directives

```js
 *ngFor="let match of virtual | groupby : 'gameid'
```

ı have like that code. and ı have a pipe . gameid is like 23342341 .

ı need to asc sorting this array by gameid. help me guys . what kind a code ı need.

```js
import { Pipe, PipeTransform, Component, NgModule} from '@angular/core';

/**
 * Generated class for the GroupbyPipe pipe.
 *
 * See https://angular.io/api/core/Pipe for more info on Angular Pipes.
 */
@Pipe({
  name: 'groupby',
})
export class GroupbyPipe implements PipeTransform {
  /**
   * Takes a value and makes it lowercase.
   */
   transform(array: Array<string>, args: string): Array<string> {
        if (array !== undefined) {
            array.sort((a: any, b: any) => {
                if ( a[args] < b[args] ){
                    return -1;
                } else if ( a[args] > b[args] ) {
                    return 1;
                } else {
                    return 0;   
                }
            });
        }
        return array;
    }

}
```

and its my pipe ts

ı found the code in google but its not work. any one will be help me how can ı sort my array on pipe by gameid (integer) ?

Comment: Did you get any error on console? Everything seems to be fine, check my working version too https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-filter

Comment: @PrithiviRaj yes . its says TypeError: Cannot read property 'sort' of undefined

Comment: Is data coming in for loop without pipes? I don't find any issues in shared code. Share the TS file and HTML file if possible

Comment: @PrithiviRaj yes i can share but ı dont think you can read my code its huge big. pipe is working another ngFor but the ngfor's data is coming local. this issies version is data coming from this.http.get like 40 times something . but when ı open the page data dont exist. is it possible that you have any suggestions?

Comment: 1. try without pipes and see whether data is displaying in HTML. 2. If data is not coming to HTML check whether the HTTP request is happening or not and check the values in virtual

Comment: @PrithiviRaj my data is coming and working **thanks**.  but when data is update its not re sorting ? ı am adding pipe pure:false but not resorting

Comment: @PrithiviRaj **have suffered you.Sorry** but ı cant resolve it.

Comment: so sorting is working on loading but it's not working after some data addition in virtual array. Am I right?

Comment: @PrithiviRaj yes. you right man.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have added changeDetectorRef to detect changes in local. sometimes data changes inside subscribe will not reflect. Below is my sample code with changeDetectorRef and slice. use both and see. [This is my working version here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-filter)

```
import { Component, ChangeDetectorRef } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
 term:string = "";
  topics = [
    {type:"NonFiction", name:"Titanic", num:2},
    {type:"Fiction", name:"Avatar", num:1},

    {type:"Tragedy", name:"MotherIndia",num:5},
  ];
  constructor(public ref : ChangeDetectorRef) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.addTopic();
  }

  addTopic(){
    setTimeout(()=>{
      console.log("triggered");
      this.topics.push({type:"share", name:"MotherIndia",num:3});
      this.topics=this.topics.slice();
      this.ref.detectChanges();
    },5000)
  }
}
```

Comment: Show me how you are inserting data into the virtual array on http request

Comment: Important piece is missing in your sample

Comment: I shortened the ts.

Comment: I have updated the code with changeDetectorRef. Try that too.

Comment: you need share url ı think. doesnt change anything